# "To be on the same page"

Tags: idioms, expressions

As you are fully aware, the using this idiom within the construction below:

- > I don't think we are on the same page.

**means:** I don't think we **understand each other**.

This idiom on the other hand has a direct connotation of **agreement** as [Macmillan](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/be-on-the-same-page) says:

> To understand and **agree** with what is being done or suggested: 
>   - I think we’re all on the same page.

I was wondering if it can imply both concepts. Please do me a favor and illustrate its common meaning by some examples.

PS, I have read the [similar thread](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40208/meaning-of-on-the-same-page), but it didn't give me the requisite information.

Answer (score 1):

Context is everything. When you think about the *literal* meaning of being "on the same page", if you were reading the same page of a book as somebody else you would be *saying the same thing*.

If people are saying the same thing in a discussion where the goal is to reach a decision, then they are naturally *in agreement*.

Again, thinking *literally* - if two people were on *different* pages of the same book, then there would be *confusion*. They would be in possession of different information, and speaking about different subjects.

If two people are saying *different* things in a discussion, it may be that they *do not understand* each other, so it does not necessarily follow that they don't agree. Sometimes people have different stakes in, or concerns about the same thing, and so discuss the same matter from different angles.

A similar idiom is "*on the same wavelength*".

Comment: Thank you. I knew that idiom, but do you mean that the two idioms "to be on the same page" and "to be on the same wavelength" mean the same thing in my both provided case above @Astralbee?

Comment: @A-friend I believe both idioms could be used *interchangeably*, but as explained in my answer, the *meaning* is determined by context. Essentially they mean that people are thinking in similar ways, but to what outcome would depend on the context.